# How is waveformData interpreted

Tags: javascript, soundcloud, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm using [Soundcloud's Waveform JS](https://github.com/soundcloud/waveformjs) to create my own audio visuals and was wondering...how is the waveformData `array` of **floating points**

```
waveform.update({
  data: [0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0] // what does the data really represent?
});
```

interpreted in relation to?

1. to its `peakData`?
2. the song's `timeDuration`?
3. what does each `array value` represent?